# Why is odeint time evolving these two differently in python?

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

I have two programs, one that can take in N coupled ODEs and one that uses 2 coupled ODEs. In the case that I input the 2 same ODEs into both codes, with the same time span, I get different answers. I know the correct answer, so I can deduce that my N many program is wrong.

Here is the code for the 2 equation dedicated one:

```
# solve the coupled system dy/dt = f(y, t)
def f(y, t):
    """Returns the collections of first-order 
    coupled differential equations"""
    #v11i = y[0]
    #v22i = y[1]
    #v12i = y[2]
    print y[0]

    # the model equations
    f0 = dHs(tRel,vij)[0].subs(v12,y[2])
    f1 = dHs(tRel,vij)[3].subs(v12,y[2])
    f2 = dHs(tRel,vij)[1].expand().subs([(v11,y[0]),(v22,y[1]),(v12,y[2])])

    return [f0, f1, f2]


# Initial conditions for graphing
v110 = 6               
v220 = 6                 
v120 = 4                  
y0 = [v110, v220, v120]       # initial condition vector

sMesh  = np.linspace(0, 1, 10e3)   # time grid

# Solve the DE's
soln = odeint(f, y0, sMesh)
```

and here is the N equation dedicated one:

```
def f(y, t):
    """Returns the derivative of H_s with initial
    values plugged in"""
    # the model equations 
    print y[0]

    for i in range (0,len(dh)):
        for j in range (0,len(y)):
            dh[i] = dh[i].subs(v[j],y[j])

    dhArray = []  
    for i in range(0,len(dh)):
          dhArray.append(dh[i])

    return dhArray

sMesh  = np.linspace(0, 1, 10e3)   # time grid
dh = dHsFunction(t, V_s).expand()
soln = odeint(f, v0, sMesh)
```

where dHs(tRel,vij) = dHsFunction(t,V_s) i.e. the exact same ODEs. Similarly y0 and v0 are the exact same. But when I print y[0] in the N many case, I get an output of:

```
6.0
5.99999765602
5.99999531204
5.97655553477
5.95311575749
5.92967598021
5.69527820744
5.46088043467
5.2264826619
2.88250493418
0.53852720647
-1.80545052124
-25.2452277984
-48.6850050755
-72.1247823527
-306.522555124
```

as opposed to the 2 dedicated case of:

```
6.0
5.99999765602
5.99999765602
5.99999531205
5.99999531205
5.98848712729
5.98848712125
5.97702879748
5.97702878476
5.96562028875
5.96562027486
5.91961750442
5.91961733611
5.93039037809
5.93039029335
5.89564277275
5.89564273736
5.86137647436
5.86137638807
5.82758984835

etc.
```

where the second result is the correct one and graphs the proper graphs.

Please let me know if more code is needed or anything else. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second version for `f` modifies the value of the global variable `dh`.
On the first call, you substitute in values in it, and these same values are then used in all subsequent calls.

Avoid that by using e.g. `dh_tmp = list(dh)` inside the function.

Comment: I'm almost certain you're right. I'm trying to iterate through each element of dh to substitute a variable for it's value if it's present. What others ways would be recommend doing this. I tried to set a tmp = dh and replace all dh with tmp and got identical results.

Comment: Reading http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects maybe clarifies the issue.